# Coefficient of determination, why?

Tags: statistics

I mean it is written in a book "Statistics for Management and Economics", that coefficient of determination is coefficient of correlation squared. Well, am I the only one to whom this is surprising fact as he expected something more clear or natural?? I mean, if someone can present me the proof why, or why some other, more natural things do not work, like I don't know, absolute value of the coefficient of correlation or something similar to Chebyshev theorem ($1-\text{coefficient of correlation}$)?

Comment: The title of the question is very confusing, could you please edit it so it is more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $n$ paired observations $(x_i,y_i)$ on $(x,y)$ and you want to predict $y$ on the basis of $x$.

You consider the prediction model $$y=\phi(x)+e$$ where $\phi$ is  the part of $y$ explained by $x$ through $\phi$ and $e$ is the unexplained part.

Suppose you see from the scatter plot of $x$ and $y$ that $\phi$ is more or less linear.

So you choose $$\phi(x)=a+bx$$

Then the least square linear predictor of $y$ obtained on the basis of $x$ is $$\hat y=\hat a+\hat b x$$, where
$$\hat a=\bar y-\hat b\bar x\quad,\quad \hat b=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(x,y)}{\operatorname{var}(x)}$$

It can be shown that

\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(\hat y)&=\operatorname{var}(\hat a+\hat b x)
\\&=\hat b^2\operatorname{var}(x)
\\&=r^2 \operatorname{var}(y)
\end{align}

, where $r$ is the correlation coefficient between $x$ and $y$.

> A measure of efficacy of the predictor $\phi$ is given by the proportion of variation in $y$ explained by $\phi$, i.e., $$\frac{\operatorname{var}(\hat y)}{\operatorname{var}(y)}=r^2$$, which is termed as coefficient of determination.

Of course, the coefficient of determination is numerically equal to the square of the correlation coefficient, but that is hardly a definition or a motivation for the former.

When $r^2=0$ the linear prediction of $y$ obtained on the basis of $x$ is worst, and when $r^2=1$ the prediction  is perfect as $\phi$ explains the variability in $y$ completely.

For more details, the following threads might be helpful:

- [Correlation Coefficient and Determination Coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129909/correlation-coefficient-and-determination-coefficient?rq=1)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123651/geometric-interpretation-of-multiple-correlation-coefficient-r-and-coefficient?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1447/coefficient-of-determination-r2-i-have-never-fully-grasped-the-interpretat?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Excellent answer